# entire functions f such that |f(z)-e^z|=e^{Re z}

Tags: complex-analysis

**Q- Find all the entire functions f such that  |f(z)-e^z|=e^{Rez} for all z $\in$ C.Justify your answer.**

I cant think of a way to start solving this problem and can you tell me what theorems that i should use to solve a problem like this and it would be great if someone could solve this as an example.

Answer (score 1):

Since $$|f(z) - e^z| = e^{\mathrm{Re}(z)} = |e^z|, \; \; z \in \mathbb{C}$$ the quotient $\frac{f(z) - e^z}{e^z}$ is a bounded entire function...

Comment: How can we conclude that the quotient is a bounded entire function?